# django rest framework How to delete redundant queries？

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use Django `debug_toolbar` to see SQL query and I want to delete the second SQL query.

```
1.(SELECT ... FROM auth_user LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts_userextension ON (auth_user.id = accounts_userextension.user_id) 50.86474349085549% 28.30 Sel 
Expl)   
2.(SELECT ... FROM auth_user LIMIT 1000  49.13525650914451%   27.34 Sel  Expl)
```

Here is `models.py` :

```
class UserExtension(models.Model):      
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_detail')
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Here is `serializers.py` :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   
from .models import UserExtension    
class UserExtensionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserExtension
        fields = '__all__'

class accountDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_detail = UserExtensionSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "first_name",
            'user_detail',
        ]
```

Here is `views.py` :

```
class AccountView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):    
    queryset = User.objects.all().select_related('user_detail')
    serializer_class = accountDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = ()
```

Comment: Drop the select realated part. Use queryset = User.objects.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the extra query is because of `user_detail = UserExtensionSerializer()`. Try below code. I've not tested but it should work.

```
class accountDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_details = UserExtensionSerializer(source='user_detail')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "first_name",
            'user_details',
        ]
```